# Why is a perfect group called a perfect group

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, terminology

A group is called perfect if we have $[G,G]=G$.

I was wondering in what sense is this group perfect?

I've never really done anything much with perfect groups so I don't really know anything about their properties and so I was wondering in what sense are they perfect? I suppose I see that it's abelianization is trivial but I don't really know what that will give?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It has no non-trivial abelian homomorphic images... The quotient of a perfect group by its center is centerless...

Answer (score 1):

The word "perfect" is used for groups, fields, numbers and other objects, but in a different sense. A *perfect number* is a positive integer $n$, which equals the sum of its divisors less than $n$. Euclid named this property "perfect". A *perfect group* is a group $G$ which has no nontrivial abelian quotients, i.e., with trivial first homology $H_1(G,\mathbb{Z})$. All non-abelian simple groups are perfect, but the converse does not hold, e.g. $SL(2,5)$ is perfect, but not simple. The smallest perfect group is $A_5$. Such groups were first called (in german) "vollkommen", and than later "perfekt". The statement that the quotient of a perfect group by its center is centerless, is called Grün's lemma.

Comment: Actually the smallest perfect group is the trivial group. (By convention, it is not simple, but it is perfect.)

Comment: Yes, the smallest non-trivial perfect group, sorry. I am trying to find a reference where this was first named (in german, I guess).

Comment: "vollkommen" sounds more like complete which (in English) means centerless and having no outer automorphisms.

Comment: This vollkommen thing is helpful. I've seen Russian users here use the English word "perfect" to mean "centerless and having no outer automorphisms", that is, the standard meaning of "complete group". So I'm happen to have a reference on the use vollkommen.